# How to remove index.php from URL in CodeIgniter using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I know this question is asked many times before and I've gone through most of them already but couldn't find a solution. I've tried most of the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35012466/how-to-remove-index-php-from-url-in-codeignitor) and in CodeIgniter official documentation. And restarted apache each time. It didn't work for me. `mod_rewrite` is already enabled in my apache server.

Weird thing is, I've a working example for WAMP (in my laptop):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /project/index.php
</IfModule>
```

It works perfectly in WAMP, but it doesn't work in LAMP. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: have you follow this step?
$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: @prakashtank Yes, I tried that.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31785445/4595675

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove index.php from Codeigniter URL in Wamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825806/remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-url-in-wamp)

Comment: Check the [Codeigniter Documentation on StackOverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/codeigniter/929/getting-started-with-codeigniter#t=201701060448411155207)

Comment: check your server rewrite_mod is enable

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I've tried those answers too, but they are not working either. I know this question can be duplicate of others, but not getting any solutions. Is there any chance that my .htaccess file is not working, provided `mod_rewrite` is already enabled?

Comment: @SujalPatel Already enabled

Comment: remove all your htaccess code and follow the instruction on the link. I used to this and 100% sure this is working fine..

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Which link in those 3 links?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770799/codeigniter-how-to-remove-index-php-from-url/31785445#31785445. but dont leave Base URL empty.. its for old version

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Not working either.
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/anoops/project';
is my base_url configuration. Any mistakes? Is there any portion I need to look for mistakes?

Comment: base URL should like this `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/path/to/root/folder';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it working with the help of following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

And I updated `<Directory /var/www/>` section of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file with:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

It solved all problems and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have used this and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code in your .htaccess file

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ROOT DIRECTORY NAME/

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<Directory "/path/to/document/root/">
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like this......

`.htaccess` inyour root directory with following code..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Set configuration in `application/config.php`  as follows..

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://domain_name';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Answer (score 0):

here it is my approach:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And also in config.php replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

and also in the same file replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

by

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```